# Jquery filter result from optselect chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

i`m tiring to get this form of result

```
job=online,print&music=tribal
```

after a button is clicked on my form:

The plug-in is chosen and i did not find any solution to get to the result in this way , so filtering the html i guess is the only way.

this is a sample

```
 <ul class="chosen-results">
     <li class="group-result">Job</li>
     <li class="result-selected group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Online</li>
     <li class="group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Dj</li>
     <li class="result-selected group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Print</li>
     <li class="active-result group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="5">Navy</li>
     <li class="group-result">Music</li>
     <li class="active-result group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="7">Jazz</li>
     <li class="active-result group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="8">Rock</li>
     <li class="active-result group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="9">House</li>
     <li class="result-selected group-option" style="" data-option-array-index="10">Tribal</li>
</ul>
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the option value and its `optgroup` label like so:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   var selected = $(this).val()
   var selectedTitlte = $(this).find("option:selected").closest("optgroup").attr("label");
   $("p").html(selectedTitlte + ":" + selected);
});
```

[**SINGLE CHOSEN**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6172jh6/3/)

**UPDATE**

For multiple you can do something like this:

```
$("select").change(function(e){
   var select = $(this);    
   var multiArray = $(this).val();
   var lastValue;

   setTimeout(function(){ 
      lastValue = multiArray.reverse()[0]
      var findCurrentTitle = select.find("option[data-text='"+lastValue+"']").closest("optgroup").attr("label");;

      $("p").append(findCurrentTitle + ":" + lastValue+"<br/>");

   },100);

});
```

[**MULTI CHOSEN**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6172jh6/4/)

**UPDATE**

Fixed the selected showing up more than once and fixed delete:

```
$('body').on("click", ".chosen-drop li.group-option", function() {
   $(".results").append("<div data-target='"+$(this).text()+"'>"+$(this).prevAll(".group-result:first").text() + ":" + $(this).text()+"</div>");

}); 

$('select').on('change', function(event, params) {
   if(params.deselected != undefined){
      $("div[data-target='"+params.deselected+"']").remove();
   }
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6172jh6/6/)

Comment: Thanks, but this works only for a single selection optgroup.

I need for multiple select optgroup, i edited fiddle 

http://jsfiddle.net/y6172jh6/3/

Comment: after the first select i get duplicates using your code, and when i remove one option does not removes from array...please help

Comment: Thanks jmore009 is fixed.